# Rackspace Cloud servers backing up

Tags: backup, cloud-computing, rackspace

Is there anyway to backup an image of a rackspace cloud server? something thats easy to do instead of running scripts backing up each db and fs.

This seems like something easy to do on EC2 and impossible to do on rackspace cloud.

Also i know rightscale can work with rackspace cloud only for ubuntu images. Is it possible to do this with rightscale easily if its not yet available directly in rackspacecloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud servers has a backup feature.  You can have up to two backup images of your machine.  I do a daily and a weekly.  I did chat with a Rackspace support person who said that it is likely that the backup image will be on the same server or storage device as the server you're backing up, so it's not ideal.  Look for the backup tab in your server control panel.

Sometime this year (soon, I believe) they're supposed to add a feature with which you can store backups to Cloud Files, which would be a better solution.

Comment: Thankyou. i actually had to have my server moved to the same physical location as my cloudfiles to do the "new" types of backup stuff